# WordPress Gravity form Custom lookup

Tags: php, mysql, gravity

I'm using gravity form and I want to know how to create a custom table lookup with my SQL database table, is this possible?

I tried using the following code, but I think this might be wrong:

```php
<?php
/********* User Custom Fields ***********/

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'mytheme_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'mytheme_extra_profile_fields' );

function mytheme_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
  $customData = get_user_meta($user->ID);
  $enroll = (isset($customData['enroll'][0]) && $customData['enroll'][0] != '') ? $customData['enroll'][0] : '';
  $department = (isset($customData['department'][0]) && $customData['department'][0] != '') ? $customData['department'][0] : '';
  $designation = (isset($customData['designation'][0]) && $customData['designation'][0] != '') ? $customData['designation'][0] : '';
  $unit = (isset($customData['unit'][0]) && $customData['unit'][0] != '') ? $customData['unit'][0] : '';

} 
?>

    <tr>
        <th><?php esc_html_e('Enroll', 'mytheme'); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_user_field_enroll" id="enroll" value="<?php echo $enroll; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><?php esc_html_e('Department', 'mytheme'); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_user_field_department" id="department" value="<?php echo $department ; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><?php esc_html_e('Designation', 'mytheme'); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_user_field_designation" id="designation" value="<?php echo $designation ; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><?php esc_html_e('Unit', 'mytheme'); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_user_field_unit" id="unit" value="<?php echo $unit ; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: i m using wordpress site where gravityform installed and i want to table look up with my other server sql table to get user data

Comment: So far you have filled some variables with data. Where is your code for the query? The code here has nothing to do with database